# How to understand "I do think he might have told us prefects, at least."

Tags: sentence-meaning

> "He's not serious?" he(Harry) muttered to Percy.
>
> "Must be," said Percy, frowning at Dumbledore. "It's odd, because he usually gives us a reason why we're not allowed to go somewhere -- the forest's full of dangerous beasts, everyone knows that. **I do think he might have told us prefects, at least**."

As I understand the bold sentence above, Percy do think Dumbledore possibly had told prefects, but for some reason, Percy were not aware of it. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percy is a prefect and he was not told the reason, so he is annoyed. See this definition of "might":

> Expressing annoyance about something that someone has not done.
>   *‘you might have told me!’*
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/might)</sub>

Comment: Can we also use 'should' to express the same meaning?, *I do think he should have told us prefects, at least.*